# What places are considered outside Greater London?

Tags: uk, london

What places are considered outside Greater London?

Bristol, Exeter, Plymouth, Cornwall,

Scotland, Manchester,

Kent

Are they considered outside Greater London?

Comment: What do mean by "outside"? The outskirts, the suburbs of London, away from the inner city (the historical centre)? Or just a different city/town altogether? Have you looked these places up in a map? I mean, [Cornwall](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cornwall/@50.4379573,-6.0770247,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x486ab7f0bf270ec9:0x6e423c85d94b4571!8m2!3d50.2660471!4d-5.0527125) is not next door to London. I would never describe Cornwall as being outside "greater London". Kent, yes. Possibly.

Comment: I'm told Washington, Paris and Beijing are outside Greater London.

Comment: Wikipedia and google maps can be very useful for finding the general location of cities - and even countries - in area of the world that are foreign to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the places you mention are well outside London. Scotland is a different country https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_London

Comment: Which is over 5 hours away from London in a high speed train :D

Comment: "_Well_ outside" arguably doesn't describe Kent, which _borders_ Greater London, and includes a few of London's outer suburbs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The boundary between Greater London and the home counties is clearly defined - it's roughly the edge of the green belt. Some of the outer boroughs of Greater London retain a county in their postal address for historical reasons. Bromley addresses are Bromley, Kent, but Bromley has been part of Greater London for as long as I can remember.

Comment: @CannonFodder: I'm thinking chiefly of Dartford, which is definitely outside Greater London as a political subdivision, but nevertheless functionally a London suburb.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fair enough. I guess we could argue it either way depending on what definition we're using. I wouldn't have called Dartford a London suburb when I was at school there, but that was a very long time ago!

Comment: The Greater London urban area includes several parts of Kent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_London_Built-up_Area